# How can I implode() a multidimensional array to a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to implode this multidimensional array into a string:

```
$smile = Array ( 
    [a] => Array ( [0] => "smile") 
    [b] => Array ( [0] => "cat"   [1] => "dog") 
    [c] => Array ( [0] => "ora"   [1] => "rita") 
    [d] => Array ( [0] => "miley" [1] => "cyrus") 
)
```

I would like it to be in a list like this:

```
smile, cat, dog, ora, rita, miley, cyrus
```

How could I go about it?

Comment: This is trivial, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using array_shift() and array_merge() to make the array as one single array then comma separate them but that did not work. :(

Comment: What do you mean by `smile, cat, dog, ora, rita, miley, cyrus`? Do you mean initiating an array, or displaying the array, or what else?

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew I mean: The values in this array to be put in another say variable as a comma separated list

Comment: Oh, for future reference say string. Look up variable types, it'll help you better questions people can answer better. A string is anything between `" "` or `' '` but single quotes are normally for character declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array has no other levels of arrays nested, I would first implode all nested arrays with a single for loop, and then implode. Like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($smile); $i++){
    if (is_array($smile[$i])){
        $smile[$i] = implode($smile[$i], ',');
    }
}

$result = implode($smile, ',');
```

If you don't know how many levels of nesting could be, you can use recursion. For example something like this should work:

```
function collapse($array, $glue = ','){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
        if (is_array($array[$i])){
            $array[$i] = collapse($array[$i], $glue);
        }
    }

    return implode($array, $glue);
}

$imploded = collapse($smile, ',');
```

Comment: Thanks Claudio. You have helped me a lot. I owe you big time.. :D

Comment: IMO, recursion is the way to go whether you know the levels or not. The end result is a function that is generically useful to later projects. However, I tend to use foreach instead of for ($i ... In the other languages I have worked in including a count in the for statement was sub-optimal. You typically wanted something like `$cnt = count($array);' followed by `for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++)` so that count($array) wasn't evaluated each iteration of the loop. I haven't tested this in PHP so it may be irrelevant.